# Easiest and the Best Way to Generate Large Chunk of HTML that Already Exist in DOM with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is the structure of my site that displays articles posted by users. The site allows users to post their own article which gets prepended to the body and displayed immediately while it is been saved to database via AJAX.

```
<div class = 'article-wrapper-outer'>
    <div class = 'article-wrapper-inner'>
        <div class = 'article-wrapper'>
            <p class = 'header-details'>
                <span class = 'name-detail'>Yax</span>
                <span class = 'time-detail'>30-11-2014 : 5:43pm</span>
                <span class = 'articleID-detail'>12</span>
            </p>
            <p class = 'main-article'>
                How do regenerate this in the easiest 
                way possible with jQuery?           
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I recreate and concatenate all these html whenever a user posts an article, changing contents of these classes:

```
name-detail
time-detail
articleID-detail
main-article
```

but I feel their should be a better way of doing this.

Is it possible for me to say:

```
var main-Article = $('.article-wrapper-outer:first').html();
```

?

If it is possible, how do I reach to these four classes and change their contents? If it is not possible, what is the best way to do this?

Comment: You're looking for a templating or databinding engine, like Knockout or Handlebars.

Comment: @SLaks: Do I have to go all that way? What I am building is not that big and I seriously would want to be able to do this jQuery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could clone the article document fragment and just replace the new parts. However, you'll find that your app will be easier to maintain and extend if you switch to an MV* framework like CanJS. Here's an example of a Todo List that shows off the same kind of features that you're adding to your app: http://todomvc.com/examples/canjs/

Below is the kind of thing that you'd have to do to manually clone and swap out values. It gets the job done but this code is a bit brittle and has little chance of being reused elsewhere.

```
$('#makeArticle').on('click', function(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();

  var $form = $(this.form);
  var name = $form.find('#name').val();
  var articleBody = $form.find('#articleBody').val();

  var $articles = $('.article-wrapper-inner'); // get all articles container
  var $newArticle = $articles.first().clone(); // clone first article

  $newArticle.find('.name-detail').text(name); // update author name
  $newArticle.find('.main-article').text(articleBody); // update article body

  $articles.prepend($newArticle); // make updated article first in articles container
});
```

jsbin example: http://jsbin.com/pezofopume/1/edit?html,js,output

Comment: This somehow not working as expected. It gets a copy of the required class but the old contents remains unchanged even after `var $articles = $('.article-wrapper-inner');
  var $newArticle = $articles.first().clone();`.

Comment: I added some comments to the code. Let me know if that helps.